# Grunt file executing error Task Serve not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Grunt file is not executing by commmand grunt serve. Here is my grunt file.

```
(function (module) {
  'use strict';

  module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // These variable would be passed in from the master build file.
    var target = grunt.option('target') || 'staging',
        version = grunt.option('product_version') || 'version_not_set';

    // config
    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('bower.json'),

      // Configuration Paths
      rootfolder: './',
      distfolder: '<%= rootfolder %>/dist/',
      srcfolder: '<%= rootfolder %>/src/',
      demofolder: '<%= rootfolder %>/demo/',
      vendorfolder: '<%= rootfolder %>/bower_components/',
      testsfolder: '<%= rootfolder %>/tests/',
      dist: {
        root: '<%= distfolder %>',
      },

      // Style Checks
      jshint: {
        files: ['<%= srcfolder %>**/*.js','!<%= srcfolder %>**/*-postfix.js', '!<%= srcfolder %>**/*-prefix.js', '<%= testsfolder %>**/*.spec.js'],
        options: {
          jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        }
      },

      // Code Cleanup for JS & HTML
      jsbeautifier: {
        files: ["<%= srcfolder %>**/*.js", '<%= testfolder %>**/*.spec.js', '<%= srcfolder %>**/*.html', '<%= srcfolder %>index.html'],
        options: {
          html: {
            braceStyle: "collapse",
            indentChar: " ",
            indentScripts: "keep",
            indentSize: 2,
            maxPreserveNewlines: 10,
            preserveNewlines: true,
            unformatted: ["a", "sub", "sup", "b", "i", "u"],
            wrapLineLength: 0
          },
          js: {
            braceStyle: "collapse",
            breakChainedMethods: false,
            e4x: false,
            evalCode: false,
            indentChar: " ",
            indentLevel: 0,
            indentSize: 2,
            indentWithTabs: false,
            jslintHappy: true,
            keepArrayIndentation: false,
            keepFunctionIndentation: false,
            maxPreserveNewlines: 10,
            preserveNewlines: true,
            spaceBeforeConditional: true,
            spaceInParen: false,
            unescapeStrings: false,
            wrapLineLength: 0
          }
        }
      },

      // Unit Testing
      karma: {
        unit: {
          configFile: 'tests/karma.conf.unit.js'
        },
        debug: {
          configFile: 'tests/karma.conf.unit.debug.js'
        },
        release: {
          configFile: 'tests/karma.conf.unit.release.js'
        }
      },

      // HTTP(S) development server
      connect: {
        devserver: {
          options: {
            hostname: '*',
            port: 8020,
            protocol: 'http',
            useAvailablePort: true,
            base: '',
            open: true,
            keepalive: true // setting this to true means this task is blocking
          }
        }
      },

      clean: {
        dist: {
          files: [{
            dot: true,
            src: [
              '.tmp',
              '<%= dist.root %>/**/*.*'
            ]
          }],
          options: {
            force: true
          }
        }
      },

      copy: {
        i18n: {
          files: [
            // includes files within path
            {expand: true, cwd: 'src/lang/', src: ['*.json'], dest: 'dist/lang', filter: 'isFile'}
          ]
        }
      },

      uglify: {
        options: {
          sourceMap: false,
          sourceMapIncludeSources: true,
          preserveComments: false,
          compress: {
            drop_console: true,
            global_defs: {
              "DEBUG": false
            },
            dead_code: true
          },
          banner: '/*\n * <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
          '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
          ' * <%= pkg.homepage %>\n' +
          ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %> (http://www.jonsamwell.com)\n' +
          ' */\n'
        },
        dist: {
          files: {
            'dist/jcs-auto-validate.min.js': ['dist/jcs-auto-validate.js']
          }
        }
      },

      concat: {
        options: {
          banner: '/*\n * <%= pkg.title || pkg.name %> - v<%= pkg.version %> - ' +
          '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %>\n' +
          ' * <%= pkg.homepage %>\n' +
          ' * Copyright (c) <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy") %> <%= pkg.author.name %> (http://www.jonsamwell.com)\n' +
          ' */\n'
        },
        dist: {
          src: [
            'src/jcs-auto-validate-prefix.js',
            'src/jcs-auto-validate.js',
            'src/providers/validator.js',
            'src/services/bootstrap3ElementModifier.js',
            'src/services/debounce.js',
            'src/services/defaultErrorMessageResolver.js',
            'src/services/foundation5ElementModifier.js',
            'src/services/validationManager.js',
            'src/directives/autoValidateFormOptions.js',
            'src/directives/formReset.js',
            'src/directives/registerCustomFormControl.js',
            'src/config/ngSubmitDecorator.js',
            'src/config/ngModelDecorator.js',
            'src/jcs-auto-validate-run.js',
            'src/jcs-auto-validate-postfix.js'
          ],
          dest: 'dist/jcs-auto-validate.js'
        }
      },

      plato: {
        analysis: {
          options: {
            title: 'AnguarJS Auto-Validate Complexity Report',
            jshint: grunt.file.readJSON('.jshintrc')
          },
          files: {
            'tests/reports/complexity': ['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*-postfix.js', '!src/**/*-prefix.js']
          }
        }
      }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-jsbeautifier');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-plato');

    // Create Custom Tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
      'jsbeautifier',
      'jshint',
      'karma:unit',
      'plato:analysis',

      'concat:dist',
      'uglify:dist',
      'copy:i18n'
    ]);
  };
}(module));
```

I have installed grunt via all require command. When i am going to run this file the command give and error: - taks serve not found. Use --force to continue..

Comment: you have add something like `grunt.registerTask('serve', [list of tasks]);` for `grunt serve` serve to work....

Answer (score 1):

grunt default
and port number is 8020